# Router which switch between two sources based on time?

Tags: router

I'd like to know where can I find a router that allows me to switch between two different ISPs based on specific hours.

I have an 20 mbit connection with 40GB/month, after them it becomes 4 mbit.
I have also a 4G SIM which provides unlimited data between midnight and 8am.

So I'd like to set my router to provide internet from my 20mbit during day and from my 4G SIM during night.

Is it possible? Which kind of hardware do I need?